# Pointers and references to struct in functions

Tags: go

I'm starting with Go and I'm having difficulty understanding pointers and references to structs inside functions.

Considering the example https://play.golang.org/p/zd8La4ecNXw

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
  Name string
}

func main() {
  // 1st
  u := User{Name: "Anne"}
  fmt.Println("1st: ", &u.Name)
  fmt.Println("1st: ", u.Name)
  Modify1(u)
  fmt.Println("1st: ", u.Name)

  // 2nd
  fmt.Println()
  v := &User{Name: "Anne"}
  fmt.Println("2nd: ", &v.Name)
  fmt.Println("2nd: ", v.Name)
  Modify2(v)
  fmt.Println("2nd: ", v.Name)

  // 3rd
  fmt.Println()
  y := &User{Name: "Anne"}
  fmt.Println("3rd: ", &y.Name)
  fmt.Println("3rd: ", y.Name)
  Modify3(&y)
  fmt.Println("3rd: ", y.Name)

  // 4th
  fmt.Println()
  z := &User{Name: "Anne"}
  fmt.Println("4th: ", &z.Name)
  fmt.Println("4th: ", z.Name)
  Modify4(z)
  fmt.Println("4th: ", z.Name)
}

func Modify1(u User) {
  fmt.Println("func: ", &u.Name)
  u.Name = "Duncan"
  fmt.Println("func: ", u.Name)
}

func Modify2(v *User) {
  fmt.Println("func: ", &v.Name)
  v = &User{Name: "Paul"}
  fmt.Println("func: ", v.Name)
}

func Modify3(y **User) {
  fmt.Println("func: ", &y)
  fmt.Println("func: ", &(*y).Name)
  *y = &User{Name: "Bob"}
  fmt.Println("func: ", (*y).Name)
}

func Modify4(z *User) {
  fmt.Println("func: ", &z.Name)
  z.Name = "John"
  fmt.Println("func: ", z.Name)
}
```

Results:

```
1st:  0x40e128
1st:  Anne
func:  0x40e140
func:  Duncan
1st:  Anne

2nd:  0x40e158
2nd:  Anne
func:  0x40e158
func:  Paul
2nd:  Anne

3rd:  0x40e188
3rd:  Anne
func:  0x40e198
func:  0x40e188
func:  Bob
3rd:  Bob

4th:  0x40e1b8
4th:  Anne
func:  0x40e1b8
func:  John
4th:  John
```

Apart from the *1st* example, where Ihave no questions, all the others seem to point to the original struct assignment, but *2nd* doesn't change the caller value.

Why does this happen, and why is this different than in *3rd* and *4th*?

Comment: `v` is a local variable in `Modify2`.

Comment: It's a local variable in all of them, but in Modify2 you're just overwriting the local variable instead of overwriting the value it points to.

Comment: I've not used SO in the last years, came back and really don't understand why people downvote when a user doesn't understand something and shows an effort to understand.

Comment: @Adrian: thanks for the comment, but cannot understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to remember is that **everything is passed by value** (a.k.a. passed by copying). When you pass a pointer to a function, that parameter is *still* a local variable in that function, containing a *copy of the pointer*. That local copy points to the same memory referenced by the caller.

When you do this:

```
v = &User{Name: "Paul"}
```

You're overwriting your *local variable* `v` with a *new* pointer to a *new* instance of `User`. It now points to different memory than the caller's pointer, so the caller sees nothing.

If you instead did this:

```
*v = User{Name: "Paul"}
```

Then the *same* pointer, pointing to the *same* memory, would be overwritten with a *new* instance of `User`.

Likewise, in `Modify3`, you have a *pointer to a pointer*. So your caller and function each have a local variable, which points to a memory location, which holds another memory location, where an actual value can be found. Note that this is a very unusual (but not unheard of) pattern in Go, but common in other languages. When you do this:

```
*y = &User{Name: "Bob"}
```

You're creating a new pointer to a new `User`, and storing that new pointer in the shared memory pointed to by the outer pointer. So, again, both function and caller are sharing memory and both will see the changes.